# Solace via NodeJS Not Waiting for Success

Tags: node.js, typescript, promise, solace

I'm trying to get Solace (a queuing system) to create a session, then send a message on that session. Instead, it listens to my session creation, receives all the event handlers (I registered all of them), fails to create that session and fails to tell me why. I cannot get this to ***WAIT*** for completion. I suspect if it had a few more microseconds, the session would be completed. The promises I have are not being kept. Any awaits that I put in are dutifully ignored.

The Typescript code below is attempting to make a connection to Solace to put a message on a queue. At a high level, it works by getting an instance of the Solace module, then it creates a Session, then with that session, it sends the message. Session creation returns an actual Session and not a promise. That doesn't mean it actually works though. Instead, you have to register an event handler. Because I don't see any of the console.log()s, I believe the createSession event handlers are not being run. Despite registering an event handler for *every* error in the session handler, Solace neither made the connection, nor said why. As far as I can tell, there's no concept of getting the current state of the session either.

Please note, in previous attempts, I was getting a WaitingForDNS error on the send. It also runs relatively quickly, so I don't think it's doing very much. When I turned on tracing, the most I could tell is that eventually Solace decided to resolve the IP address.

Please see my wishes annotated below:

```
export class TopicPublisher {
    public async connect() {

        // Return me a Promise for the Session; either the Session is fully loaded
        // loaded, or it's rejected
        return new Promise<Session>((resolve, reject) => {
            if (this.session !== null) {
                this.log("Already connected and ready to publish");
                reject();
            }

            try {

                this.session = this.solace.SolclientFactory.createSession({
                    // solace.SessionProperties
                    url: this.hosturl,
                    vpnName: this.vpn,
                    userName: this.username,
                    password: this.pass,
                    connectRetries: 1,
                });
            } catch (error: any) {
                this.log('Error on creating session: ' + error.toString());
                reject(error);
            }

            //The UP_NOTICE dictates whether the session has been established
            this.session.on(solace.SessionEventCode.UP_NOTICE, () => {
                // *** At this point, return the session as a successfully completing promise ***
                this.log("=== Successfully connected and ready to subscribe. ===");
                resolve(this.session);
            });

            //The CONNECT_FAILED_ERROR implies a connection failure
            this.session.on(solace.SessionEventCode.CONNECT_FAILED_ERROR, (sessionEvent: { infoStr: string; }) => {
                this.log("Connection failed to the message router: " + sessionEvent.infoStr + " - check correct parameter values and connectivity!");
                reject(`Check the settings in game-config.ts and try again!`);
            });

            // Register every event handler in vain attempt at getting Solace to tell me
            // why it does not work
            let otherErrors = [
                solace.SessionEventCode.DOWN_ERROR,
                solace.SessionEventCode.REJECTED_MESSAGE_ERROR,
                solace.SessionEventCode.SUBSCRIPTION_ERROR,
                solace.SessionEventCode.SUBSCRIPTION_OK,
                solace.SessionEventCode.VIRTUALROUTER_NAME_CHANGED,
                solace.SessionEventCode.REQUEST_ABORTED,
                solace.SessionEventCode.REQUEST_TIMEOUT,
                solace.SessionEventCode.PROPERTY_UPDATE_OK,
                solace.SessionEventCode.PROPERTY_UPDATE_ERROR,
                solace.SessionEventCode.CAN_ACCEPT_DATA,
                solace.SessionEventCode.RECONNECTING_NOTICE,
                solace.SessionEventCode.RECONNECTED_NOTICE,
                solace.SessionEventCode.REPUBLISHING_UNACKED_MESSAGES,
                solace.SessionEventCode.ACKNOWLEDGED_MESSAGE,
                solace.SessionEventCode.UNSUBSCRIBE_TE_TOPIC_OK,
                solace.SessionEventCode.UNSUBSCRIBE_TE_TOPIC_ERROR,
                solace.SessionEventCode.MESSAGE,
                solace.SessionEventCode.GUARANTEED_MESSAGE_PUBLISHER_DOWN
            ];
            for (let errorCodeIndex = 0; errorCodeIndex < otherErrors.length; errorCodeIndex++) {
                this.log('Registering error handler code: '+otherErrors[errorCodeIndex]);
                this.session.on(otherErrors[errorCodeIndex], (sessionEvent: { infoStr: string; }) => {
                    this.log("Connection failed with error code : " + otherErrors[errorCodeIndex] + " " + sessionEvent.infoStr);
                    reject(`Check the config settings`);
                });
            }

            //DISCONNECTED implies the client was disconnected
            this.session.on(solace.SessionEventCode.DISCONNECTED, (sessionEvent: any) => {
                this.log("Disconnected.");
                if (this.session !== null) {
                    this.session.dispose();
                    //this.subscribed = false;
                    this.session = null;
                }
            });

            try {
                this.session.connect();
            } catch (error: any) {
                reject();
            }

        });
    };

    public async publish(topicName: string, payload: any) {
        // This builds a message payload, it works fine
        let solaceMessage = this.getSolaceMessage(topicName, payload);

        try {
            // *** It does *not* wait for the connection ***
            console.log('@@This point is reached');
            let localSession = await this.connect();
            // UP_EVENT ***SHOULD*** have happened, but it does not wait for any events 
            // or promises to be completed.
            console.log('@@This point is reached');
            console.log('localSession =' + localSession);
            localSession.send(solaceMessage);
        } catch (error) {
        }
    };
}

let topicPublisher: TopicPublisher = new TopicPublisher(getInitializedSolaceModule(),
    argumentParser.hosturl,
    argumentParser.usernamevpn,
    argumentParser.username,
    argumentParser.vpn,
    argumentParser.pass,
    argumentParser.topicName);
topicPublisher.publish(argumentParser.topicName, readMessageFromFile(argumentParser.messageFileSpecification)).then(() => {
    console.log('@@This point is reached');
}, () => {
    console.log('@@BP10.5 Error handler on publish');
}

).catch(error => {
    console.log('publish error' + error);
});
console.log('@@This point is reached');
topicPublisher.disconnect();
console.log('@@This point is reached');
```

Solace API documentation is at https://docs.solace.com/API-Developer-Online-Ref-Documentation/nodejs/index.html, but I'm not sure this is a Solace error.

Comment: "*I don't see any of the console.log()s*" - please post the logs that you *do* get

Comment: What is `this.log`? Did you mean `console.log`?

Comment: Why are you immediately calling `topicPublisher.disconnect();`? What does that method do?

Comment: @Bergi I removed some of the logs for brevity. This.log effectively is console.log

Comment: @Bergi Disconnect should happen if an error occured or service is done being used. It's not unlike closing a file.

Comment: Well yes, but you are not disconnecting after the service was used, you are disconnecting immediately after starting to use the service. Put the `disconnect` call inside a `then` callback!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have great exposure to TypeScript - is it possible that the check 'this.session !== null' ends up rejecting the promise, and no session is created. An uninitialized value, if it holds undefined, a `!== null` check would fail. Maybe your log output sequence can shed light on this.

My apologies, this is a silly point, and not offering any direct help.